# Rails 4: Collect date in form and then save it as unix timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to capture a date via a for field

```
<%= f.date_field(:custom_start_date) %>
```

and then save the date to the database as a unix timestamp. In the database `custom_start_date` is of the type integer.

The params capture the following `"custom_start_date"=>"2016-09-01"`.  This looks like a time format to me, but the error message tells me, that it is a `fixnum` with the value 2016.

What is the best way to

1. Capture a date in a form
2. Convert the date to a unix timestamp
3. Save the unix timestamp to the database along with the other data captured in the form?

Is it possible to handle the conversion to the timestamp in the form before passing it into params, or should the conversion happen in the controller? When I do `@item.custom_start_date.to_time.to_i` in the controller the data already has been converted to `fixnum` 2016.

Update
I am able to access the date in its original format like in the controller like this `puts item_params[:custom_start_date]` which returns `"2016-09-01"` and `puts item_params[:custom_start_date].to_time.to_i` returns `1472688000`. As soon as I assign the `params` to `@item = Item.new(item_params)` I believe that `custom_start_date` is coerced into a `fixnum` because the field is saved as an integer in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your params before do @item.save. In custom_start_date, it should be on the right format. In that case, you do @item.custom_start_date = params["custom_start_date"].to_time.to_i, for instance

Comment: When I add `@item.custom_start_date = params["custom_start_date"].to_time.to_i` I receive the following error: `undefined method 'to_time' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? to_i`

Comment: When I run `puts @item.custom_start_date` just prior to running `@item.custom_start_date = params["custom_start_date"].to_time.to_i` the `puts` prints `2016` in the console.